# Extract a method chain in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, methods, chaining

Given a function which performs a set of operations

```
const addSum = arr => arr.map(i => i+1).filter(i => i % 2 !== 0).map(i => i+1)
```

Is there a way to extract the method chain? For example, get a tree of the operations performed in an object like

```
{map: {filter: "map"}}
```

Edit: Updated example

Comment: I don't understand the optput. Nor the example. `reduce` -> `map` will not work, since you're reducing into a primitive, not an array so you can't map over the result. Even if `reduce` gave an array, how does the result correspond to the operations? The operations are sequential, none of them are nested.

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Even if this was valid, I'm not sure what problem this would solve. Can you offer some context, please? See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to create an automated documenter that can take a function performing a set of method chainings and show the transformations it goes through as a graph. I have a system that creates pipelines using method chaining and it would be nice to document those with graphs. I updated the example

Comment: No you can not. These come from lambda calculus and lambda calculus is not reversible. It's declarative. Once a function, say returns 5, there is no way of knowing how it got there. The alternative, for example quantum programming, is reversible computing and can do such things (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing). You will have to parse the code as a string and extract the chains yourself.

Comment: @sinanspd you can use an AST parser to see what's actually happening. Moreover, it's possible to know to know what each operation will produce - TypeScript and Flow, for example, examine code and can infer what the result of `reduce` or `map` would be, so it's possible to know if the transformations were, say, `string[] -> number[] -> string` or `string[] -> number[] -> string[]`. However, writing such a system is out of scope for SO - it's entirely too broad.

Comment: @VLAZ AST parsers still parse the code to do that. You are technically writing half of a compiler at that stage (which is fine if you really need to). This is very different how reversible computing works. But yes you are correct, you can always do that, but that is not necessarily a feature of the language. Regarding your latter point, out of curiosity can you actually intercept the type inference and extract that info?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think documentation like `{map: {filter: "map"}}` will be very helpful, because you could wrap `.map().filter().map()` into a single `.reduce()`. You could easily have two chains that produce identical output given the same input, one with the 'documentation' of `{map: {filter: "map"}}` and the other with just `"reduce"` (I'm not sure how you plan to document a 'chain' consisting of a single method).

Comment: @sinanspd can you intercept the type inference from another type system? I don't actually know - never tried it. I was more thinking about if you had your own type system, as part of a code parser, then you'd be able to extract the information. But, yes, that does involve basically writing your own compiler.

Comment: Haskell and PureScript can infer the type of a function, but the type they infer is more useful than just a list of chained methods (or composed functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the name of the extension methods and the callback in a 2D array. Then use `reduce` to call each function one by one and return the result as accumulator in each iteration

```js
const sequence = (initial, ops) => ops.reduce((acc, [f, cb]) => acc[f](cb), initial)

// Save each opeartion in: ["extension name", callback] format
const operations = [
  ['map', i => i + 1],
  ['filter', i => i % 2],
  ['map', i => i + 2]
]

const output = sequence([1, 2, 3], operations)

console.log(output)
```

Or, you could use a `pipe` function used in functional pattern

```js
const increment = n => arr => arr.map(i => i + n)
const evenFilter = arr => arr.filter(i => i % 2)

function pipe(...fns) {
  return arg => fns.reduce((prev, fn) => fn(prev), arg);
}

console.log(
  pipe(increment(1), evenFilter, increment(2))([1, 2, 3])
)
```